# Can not figure out where to put the '\n' in my code in order for regex to print line by line.

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, text

So I have been at this for a while now trying to figure out where to put the '\n' in order for the output being set into a text document to be placed line by line. It is grouping the output into one big mess.  I wanted for each line that matches my regex, to be saved on a seperate line.

Code:

```
import re


dns = []
with open('ns.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.read().splitlines()
    for line in lines:
        if re.search(r'^(add lb vserver )(\S+) (\S+) (\S+)(.+)$', "line"):
            dns.append(line)
            print(dns)
    with open('dnsout.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: shouldn't you write `dns` instead of `lines`?

Comment: `"line"` is incorrect. Remove the quotation marks.

Answer (score 1):

`dns.append(line)` must be `dns.append(line+"\n")`.

Answer (score 0):

***updated*** (sorry for typo's)

Since you're reading in all the lines into an array anyway.
Just read the entire file into a string.

Then clean it up with a find `(?m)$(?:\s*\r?\n)+` replace `\r\n`

Use whatever CRLF translation your system uses.
This just removes all extra linebreaks.

If you want to make it with an extra line separation, make the replacement `\r\n\r\n`.